# Algorithm to sort items between different lists

Tags: javascript, algorithm, jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to implement an algorithm to sort items in the same list or different list and save the result in a Database.

The code to sort the items in the GUI is already there. 
I am using jquery-ui which is able to give me the index of the new position.

**Example 1:**
Let's suppose I have two items in the same list.
If I move the *first item* in place of the `second item` I am able to get the value `1` (which is the position of the second item).

I am using javascript for implementing the code but actually I am interesting in a `pseudo code`.

If I have to sort items in the same list the story is quite simple.
The data model should look like this:

```
firstItem: {
  id: 5,
  next: 0
},
secondItem: {
  id: 3
  next: 1
}
```

When I move the `firstItem` in place of the `secondItem` I can change the model in this way:

```
firstItem.prev = firstItem.next;
firstItem.next = newIndex;
secondItem.next = firstItem.prev;
```

**Example 2:**
Let's suppose I would like to sort the items between different lists.
Here is the story becomes quite complicated I suppose:
The model should looks like this:

```
// list 1
item_0_0 = {
  id: 12,
  list_id: 0,
  next: 0
}
item_0_1 = {
  id: 13,
  list_id: 0,
  next: 1
}

// list 2
item_1_0 = {
  id: 45,
  list_id: 1,
  next: 0
}
item_1_1 = {
  id: 35,
  list_id: 1,
  next: 1
}
```

if I move the `item_0_0` between the `item_1_0` and the `item_1_1` the models should looks like this:

```
item_0_1 = {
  id: 13,
  list_id: 0,
  next: 0 // 1 -> 0 because the previous-one has been moved in another list
}

item_1_0 // does not change because I insert the item_0_0 after

item_1_1 = {
  id: 35,
  list_id: 1,
  next: 2 // 1->2 it changes because I inserted the item_0_0 before
}

item_0_0 = {
  id: 12,
  list_id: 1, // 0->1 I need to change the list
  next: 1 // this is the new position in the new list
}
```

My question is what is the best code to update the lists in this case?

Here is my pseudo code:

```
item_0_0.list_id = newListID;
item_0_0.prev = item_0_0.next;
item_0_0.next = newIndex;
item_0_1.next = item_0_1.next - 1; // actually it should be iterated 
                                   // between all items after!
item_1_1.next = item_1_1.next + 1;  // actually it should be iterated
                                   // between all items after!
```

P.S.:
1) `newIndex` and `newListID` comes from the javascript library.
2) I suppose the list well sorted before to start to move the items.

Comment: If you want a solution you must provide the code/api for the lists. No we only know about the data. For your problem: Assuming both list are in order: Remove the item from list 1 and fix the gab between the two neighboring elements, then attach the element to the front/back of the other list and run a simple loop to determine its position. This will work in a maximum of `n` iterations but only if the lists are in order.

Comment: From where does `newIndex` come from? mentioned in `firstItem.next = newIndex;` and `item_0_0.next = newIndex;`

Comment: @Ankush I am going to update my question with your comment. See the button of the page. thanks.

Comment: @LorraineBernard ok. I don't see where are you sorting? All I see is pointer assignment or increment/decrement code. Where is comparison between id? Is this some kind of merge sort between two lists?

Comment: @Ankush I should write a piece of code. I will update the question later. thanks for your comment.